# Trouble calling powershell script that invokes SQL queries from c#

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, powershell

I already have a Powershell script that does a sql query and formats the results and emails them to an email address specified as a command line arg to the script. It also attaches a CSV of the results if desired.

I'm trying to build a web front end to the powershell script for less than fans of cmd line usage. I'm using C# from an ASP web page.  Running the script from command line works fine, but when I run the script from the web page, I get a TSQL error.  I've debugged the script to know that it is running the script with proper arguments, but fails when it hits the Invoke-SqlCmd commandlet.  I didn't see anything for this error on stackoverflow or the rest of google.
Suggestions?

```
Unhandled Execution Error
[ParserException]
   ManagedBatchParser.Parser.Parse() +170
   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.ExecutionProcessor.ExecuteTSql(String sqlCommand) +275

[CmdletInvocationException]
   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input) +485
   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Pipeline.Invoke() +84
   _Default.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +660
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +154
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3707
```

PowerShell Script:

```
$serverName="server"
$dbName="perfmon"

$mailServer="exchange"
$mailUser="testUser"
$mailPass="pass"

$workingPath="D:\scripts"
$scriptFile=$workingPath + "\queryStats.sql"
$tmpSql=$workingPath + "\tmpSql.sql"
$timeout="600"

$mailPass=ConvertTo-SecureString $mailPass -AsPlainText -Force
$cred=New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($mailUser,$mailPass)


$fromEmail="perfmonDB@test"
$toEmail=$args[0]
$getCSV=$args[1]


#add SQL snap ins
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100

$sqlCommand= "Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $serverName -Database $dbName -InputFile $tmpSql -QueryTimeout $timeout"
echo "$sqlCommand" >> $workingPath\log.txt
$results=Invoke-Expression $sqlCommand

$emailResults = $results | format-table| Out-String
$emailResults = $results | convertto-html -property MachineName, InstanceName, CounterName, Average, Minimum, Maximum| Out-String
if($getCSV -eq "Yes")
{
  $csvResults = $results | Convertto-csv
  $results | Export-Csv $workingPath\results.csv
  Send-MailMessage -To ($toEmail) -Subject "Perfmon Query Results" –From ($fromEmail) -Body $emailResults -Credential $cred -SmtpServer ($mailServer) -BodyAsHtml -Attachments $workingPath\results.csv
}
else {
Send-MailMessage -To ($toEmail) -Subject "Perfmon Query Results" –From ($fromEmail) -Body $emailResults -Credential $cred -SmtpServer ($mailServer) -BodyAsHtml

}
Remove-item $workingPath\tmpSql.sql
Remove-item $workingPath\results.csv
```

Comment: IS "Unhandled Execution Error" the entirety of the exception message info, can you debug and see what the inner exception message is.  My guess would be the problem is that the user that asp.net process is running as does not have permission to execute the script or access the script.  Also post the code that causes the exception, stack traces are not very useful if you can't see the code.

Comment: That's all I get from the web page output.  I did the asp dev on another box and am install visual studio on the SQL box to do the debug.  I'll give that a try and I posted the powershell script I'm using above. Thanks

Comment: Solved.  You got it, it was a permissions issue.  I created a new user account on the box, create a sql login/user and gave them read only permissions, and then changed the application pool in IIS to match the new windows user.  After that it runs correctly. Thanks!